# Unable to connect with MySQL from Python 2.7. (Unable to connect to localhost)

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, server, windows-7, connection

I am trying to run a module in python2.7 on my Windows 7 PC but it seems that I cannot connect with MySql server. The error I get is the following:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

1) Python module I am trying to run: https://snipboard.io/eaZNSn.jpg

2) Error I get: https://snipboard.io/761UoR.jpg

3) MySql installer: https://snipboard.io/o35n2l.jpg

4) Windows Services: https://snipboard.io/CI9JPa.jpg  , MySql80 starts properly, Mysql cannot start.

5) Mysql: https://snipboard.io/iuaVEA.jpg

What I have tried: installing the mysqld.exe from cmd. https://snipboard.io/qYafIM.jpg

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Don't add screenshots of code, add **code**. This makes it easier for us, volunteers, to help you by being able to copy code, and helps you to get easier answers + not having to screencap and upload everything.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the MySQL server is running on port 10061? The default port for MySQL is 3306. Try to connect using port 3306 from the python module.